# Greying out form options based on other selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm wondering if there is a JavaScript / jQuery to grey out drop-down selections based on what the user has previously chosen. 
For example,

```
<select id="cpu" name="cpu" onchange="calculateTotal()"> 
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="A6">AMD A6 Dual Core (£56)</option>
            <option value="A8">AMD A8 Quad Core (£72)</option>
            <option value="760k">Athlon 760k Quad (£72)</option> 
            <option value="A10">AMD A10 Quad Core (£119)</option> 
            </select> 

<select id="mobo" name="mobo" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="None">None</option> 
            <option value="DS2">Gigabyte A88X-DS2 (£45)</option>
            <option value="D3H">Gigabyte A88X D3H (£60)</option>
            <option value="A88X-M">ASUS A88X-M Plus (£67)</option> 
            <option value="A88X-UP4">Gigabyte A88X-UP4 (£109)</option> 
            </select>
```

Let's say the user chooses "AMD A6 Dual Core" (value="A6"), but that isn't compatible with the "Gigabyte A88X-DS2" (value="DS2"), so that option would be greyed out, so the user can't select it.

Is there any way of doing this? 
Thanks in advance

EDIT 1;
Quick question, is there a way to make it so that if the user chooses a different cpu the non-compatible mobo will become available again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
add non compatible elements in data-nonCompatible attribute, if there are two or more non compatible elements separate them by comma.
html

```
<select id="cpu" name="cpu"> 
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <!--add elements non compatible in the data-nonCompatible attribute separated by comma-->
    <option data-nonCompatible="DS2" value="A6">AMD A6 Dual Core (£56)</option>
    <option data-nonCompatible="" value="A8">AMD A8 Quad Core (£72)</option>
    <option data-nonCompatible="" value="760k">Athlon 760k Quad (£72)</option> 
    <option data-nonCompatible="" value="A10">AMD A10 Quad Core (£119)</option> 
</select> 

<select id="mobo" name="mobo" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="None">None</option> 
    <option value="DS2">Gigabyte A88X-DS2 (£45)</option>
    <option value="D3H">Gigabyte A88X D3H (£60)</option>
    <option value="A88X-M">ASUS A88X-M Plus (£67)</option> 
    <option value="A88X-UP4">Gigabyte A88X-UP4 (£109)</option> 
</select>
```

---

jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cpu').on('change',function(){
             $('#mobo option').css({'display':'block','background-color':'#FFF'})
        var foo=$('option:selected').attr('data-nonCompatible').split(',')
        for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
            $('#mobo option[value="'+foo[i]+'"]').css({'background-color':'red'})
            //If you want the elements do not appear in the list
            //$('#mobo option[value="'+foo[i]+'"]').css({'display':'none'})
            }

        })
});
</script>
```